# Will the join order influence the query speed?

Tags: mysql, database, join

When i Read the book **"database system implemention"**, it said that:

[image]
So I  confuse that , in MySQL，whether the order of inner join influence the query speed  ？
For example , I have two table :a very big table Atable and a small table Btable.

```
SELECT *
FROM Atable INNER JOIN
     Btable
     ON Atable.id = Btable.id;

SELECT *
FROM Btable INNER JOIN
     Atable
     ON Atable.id = Btable.id ;
```

My question is **will they  have the same query time ?**
**If they are different , which is faster ?**

Comment: For that particular case, there should be no effect on performance.  The description in the book is a *logical* description of what happens.  Database optimizers are free to choose among many different `JOIN` algorithms to implement the functionality.

Comment: With an INNER JOIN MySQL will try to optimise it into the best order. Most of the time it makes a good job of this. Sometimes it fails badly, and then a STRAIGHT_JOIN is useful to force the order of the JOINs (I had a case last week where a query took 120 seconds with INNER JOINs, and about 0.006 of a second when switched to STRAIGHT_JOINs)